# Реализовать функцию вычисления значения Фибоначчи с однократным вызовом рекурсии

Tags: java

Не могу понять как как сделать однократным вызовом рекурсии

```
public static int fib(int n){
    if (n==1||n==2){ 
        return 1;
    }
  return result=fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
}
```

Comment: Написать условие, как еще.

Answer (score 3):

Можно классическое решение циклом преобразовать в tail-рекурсию:

```
public static int fib1(int n, int a, int b){
if (n<=2){ 
    return a + b;
}
  return fib1(n-1, b, a + b);
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(fib1(i, 0, 1));
    }
}
```

Пример на [ideone](https://ideone.com/10ULaL)

Answer (score 0):

Ваша функция должна возвращать объект с двумя полями: значение n-ного элемента последовательности и n-1

```java
class Pair {
    private final int prev;
    private final int cur;
    public Pair(int prev, int cur) {
        this.prev = prev;
        this.cur = cur;
    }

    public int getPrev() {
        return prev;
    }

    public int getCur() {
        return cur;
    }
}

private static Pair internalFib(int n) {
    if (n == 1) { 
        return new Pair(0, 1);
    }
    Pair prev = internalFib(n - 1);
    return new Pair(prev.getCur(), prev.getPrev() + prev.getCur());
}

public static int fib(int n){
    return (n > 0) ? internalFib(n).getCur() : 0;
}
```

Comment: Чет сложно, что такое Pair<Integer, Integer> internalFib(int n) . Я так понял задача не подразумевает решения на простом уровне, на том на котором она написана

Comment: @Mobsman обычный стандартный [класс](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Pair.html) с двумя полями. Можете объявить свой аналогичный. Цель - вернуть из функции два значения

Comment: @Mobsman не нравится стандартный класс - вот вам велосипед

Answer (score 0):

Ещё одна реализация [хвостовой рекурсии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F). Идея в том чтобы вычислять результат на аргументах рекурсивного вызова. Если вы всё сделали верно, то код должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
def tail_rec_func(...):
    ...
    return tail_rec_func(...)
```

Главное требование: рекурсивный вызов должен быть последним действием в функции перед вызовом `return`. Обычно такой набор параметров непривычен для пользователя. Поэтому рекурсивная функция `fib_iter` завёрнута в `fib` с нормальным интерфейсом. У `fib_iter` нарочно сделан избыточный интерфейс, чтобы было проще выразить инвариант, который соблюдается при вызовах. В "оптимизированном" виде параметер `n` отсутствует, а `k` считает от `n - 1` до нуля:

```
public class FibonacciTailRecursion {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        for (int n = 0; n < 47; ++n) {
            System.out.println("fib(" + n + ") = " +  fib(n));
        }
    }

    public static int fib(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        // fib_iter(n, 1, f[0], f[1])
        return fib_iter(n, 1, 0, 1);
    }

    // fib_iter(n, k, f[k - 1], f[k])
    private static int fib_iter(int n, int k, int a, int b) {
        if (k == n) {
            return b;
        }
        // fib_iter(n, k + 1, f[k], f[k + 1] = f[k - 1] + f[k])
        return fib_iter(n, k + 1, b, a + b);
    }
}
```

> ```
> fib(0) = 0
> fib(1) = 1
> fib(2) = 1
> fib(3) = 2
> fib(4) = 3
> fib(5) = 5
> fib(6) = 8
> fib(7) = 13
> fib(8) = 21
> fib(9) = 34
> fib(10) = 55
> ...
> fib(45) = 1134903170
> fib(46) = 1836311903
> ```

И в конце приманка: числа Фибоначчи можно вычислять ещё быстрее с помощью [быстрого возведения в степень](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C). Тоже можно сделать хвостовой рекурсией.